# Accessing URL parameters with python requests in an i-framed app

Tags: django, iframe, python-requests, url-parameters

I am developing an Django app that that needs to consume a third party restful-API. The app itself is accessible after authentication from a portal where is exposed within an i-frame. When you select the app in the portal it redirects to the app url and appends a url parameter "?tokenid". This needs to be retrieved in order to use the third party API which needs to include the tokenid parameter as a cookie.

In my app there is a services.py module where I build all API methods to access this third party API, for instance:

```
url='https://www.fooapp.com'
token = request.get(url, 'tokenid')
cookies = {'session': token }
```

when clicking in the app link from within the main portal the response appends the tokenid parameter:

```
''https://www.fooapp.com/?tokenid=.eJwty8FqhDAQANB_mbMs2axmjKf-x1JkdCYyEGNxDK0s---V0uM7vBcoSzn0OGF4wb5lMRieMFXNrGUZVyq0yA6fDRznl8AA1S42UJUv5Kq26lIl36ZMRWwXO7bzo1RdKH_TeVOBdwNGax4LrTL-NXSRXJq4jeERKUjybY9eZMZpZu87xIgxCcP_NDHTrVz559rjTI-AQVzXchdSdM57h3Pn7yR9knvLGCj1kSnA-xcnjUmc.XNmOdg.hbtMmT5BkmOkhklP3JqgksDijhc''
```

then one of the functions to use one the API method is:

```
def get_foo():
    url = 'https://thirdparty.com/api/v0/foo/'
    r = requests.get(url, params=cookies)
    data = r.json()
    foos_dict = {foo['name']:foo['id'] for foo in data if 'name' in foo and 'id' in foo}
    return foo_dict
```

then in my views I call this function etc:

```
class Foo(generic.TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        foo_dict = services.get_foo()
        return render(request, 'foo.html', foo_dict)
```

I get this

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='wwww.foo.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?tokenid (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000002261DFCCA20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

I also tried using

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse
url = 'https://wwww.foo.com/'
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
token = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['?tokenid']
```

with no success.

Is there any other way of achieving this. I am puzzled here. What I think I don't really get is that this token id is already retrievable since I am a user inside the portal and the app is called from inside the portal, so there is no need to use request.get again (??). Any url in the iframe is appended with that ?tokenid parameter and it's valid for one hour. Any idea what could be wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This is quite hard to understand, not helped by your use of `cookies` to refer to the params dict that has nothing to do with cookies. But the main thing I don't follow is the relationship between the first bit of code and the rest. Where is that first code? Where is it called from? How is the misnamed `cookies` getting into the `get_foo` function?

Comment: I know it is quite difficult. Better with drawings.(I am not sure why they call cookies to that params dict.).The first bit of code lives in my app. The second bit of code is what I get when I click in the app link from the main portal where the app is displayed.  see [this](http://sketchtoy.com/68945239)